# Missing right parenthesis subquery

Tags: sql

This query returns missing right parenthesis although when I run the inside query it runs fine.

```
 select t.id 
 from
 (select
  v.id,
  max(c.image_type_id),
  max(vp.x), 
  max(vp.y),
  max(vp.z)
  FROM
  v,
  vp,
  c,
  WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
  group by v.id;) t
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove semicolon `;` and `,`

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM
(SELECT
 v.id,
 max(c.image_type_id),
 max(vp.x), 
 max(vp.y),
 max(vp.z)
 FROM
 v,
 vp,
 c       // HERE the comma
 WHERE v.id = vp.id 
 AND v.id = c.id
 GROUP BY v.id) t  // HERE the semicolon
```

Comment: This query is part of a bigger query and for some reason when I did this it affected the other parts of the code

Answer (score 2):

Just remove semicolon and last comma. Try to run below code.

```
 select t.id 
 from
 (select
  v.id,
  max(c.image_type_id),
  max(vp.x), 
  max(vp.y),
  max(vp.z)
  FROM
  v,
  vp,
  c
  WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
  group by v.id) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that semi-colon.

The semi-colon basically says to the interpreter "this is the end of an sql statement." If you have a semi-colon in the middle of your sql, it's going to treat everything before and everything after each as individual statements.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon at the end is culprit.

```
select t.id 
 from
 (select
  v.id,
  max(c.image_type_id),
  max(vp.x), 
  max(vp.y),
  max(vp.z)
  FROM
  v,
  vp,
  c,
  WHERE v.id = vp.id 
  AND v.id = c.id
  group by v.id)t
```